# Stop function until clicked ok or cancel - JQUERY

Tags: javascript, promise, confirm

i created custom confirm box like this:

```
function formPopup(message, callback) {
    message = message + '<div class="clear"></div><button class="mybutton" name="check" value="true">Yes</button>' +
            '<button class="mybutton mybutton2" name="check" value="false">No</button>';
    createPopup("Message", message);

    $(".popup .body button[name='check']").bind("click", function (e) {
        val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "true") {
            $(".popup").find(".close").trigger("click");
            typeof (callback) != "undefined" ? callback() : null;
        } else {
            $(".popup").find(".close").trigger("click");
        }
    });
}
```

i want when i run formPopup function the page wait like "confirm" or "alert" until i will click on `$(".popup .body button[name='check']")`.

i tried with

```
promise and when
```

but its didnt helped.

tnx a lot

Comment: does the popup display?

Comment: It may be significantly simpler for you to use a custom alert library like [Sweet Alert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert)

Comment: It's impossible to synchronously wait for a formPopup like it is with `alert` or `prompt`. You have to make your code asynchronous. Show us how you tried to use promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

jQuery could not get "this" in your click function, i replaced it with e.target, so event.target == the button that you are clicking.

```js
function showPopup(message, callback) {
    $(".popup").css("display", "block");
    $(".title").html(message);
    
    // only button 1, value will be true anyways, but just to show how to access the button object
    $(".b1").on("click", (e) => {
        var val = $(e.target).val();
        if (val == "true") {
          closePopup();
          typeof (callback) != "undefined" ? callback() : null;

        } else {
          closePopup();
        }
    });
    
    // button 2, try to split as much as you can, makes everything alot easier
    $(".b2").on("click", (e) => {
       closePopup();
    });
}

function closePopup() {
    $(".popup").css("display", "none");
    setTimeout(() => {
      showPopup("back again", () => { console.log("callback"); });
    }, 2000);
}

showPopup("message", () => { console.log("callback"); });
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.popup-content {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
  height: 100px;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clear">
</div>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <h1 class="title"></h1>
    <button class="b1" name="check" value="true">Yes</button>
    <button class="b2" name="check" value="false">No</button>
  </div>
</div>
```